# $filter is not a function while running the test case for custom filter?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am new to `unit test` and have written unit test for custom filter and I am getting the error,

> $filter is not defined.

**Here is my code:**

*For Unit Test:*

```
describe('filter', function() {

    beforeEach(module('usp'));

    var $filter;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$filter_){
        $filter = _$filter_;
    }));

    it('should format the date in this format MMM-DD-YYYY', function() {
      var dateFormat = $filter('dateFormat');
      expect(dateFormat('13-10-2016')).toEqual('10-13-2016');
    });
});
```

*Custom filter:*

```
angular.module('usp').filter('dateFormat', function () {
     return function (input) {
         return moment(input).format("MMM-DD-YYYY");
     };
 });
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: did you inject the $filter dependency in the controller?

Comment: yes, this custom filter is working in application...... and here $filter is just a variable name and to that variable assigning the function wright?

Comment: your variable is fine but if you haven't injected the dependency it will still throw an error "not defined" see Hiro's code that's what I meant by injecting $filter in the controller, I didn't put it as an answer because I want to know if you already have injected it first.

Comment: I got know here problem is with the injector, that is not working....I am getting error :Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/modulerr?p, can you please tell me how to resolve this error

Comment: can you show us your controller? surely you're using a controller to use your filter. moduler error means $filter is not injected

Answer (score 1):

You just need to inject `$filter` into your controller
Example :

```
var MyApp = angular.module('appName', []);
MyApp.controller('IndexController', ['$scope','$filter'],function($scope, $filter) {
/* Your Code here  */
});
```

Comment: how can I inject $filter in test case because this filter are custom filter and calling by services so in controller $filter injection is not there, I have to do in test case only, how can I do this?